# Weird data structure while converting from csv to list

Tags: python, csv

Bit of background i'm building a twitch irc bot just out of boredom and trying to learn some Python. The code worked when i used a textfile to store the words in that i want banned in my irc chat but i want to use CSV.

Could anyone explain why this code bellow returns a list with this structure

`[['something','something2']]`

```
def getWordList():
f = open('swearWords.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
tempList = list(reader)
print tempList
return tempList
```

while i need this structure `['something','something2']`
So i can compare it with this code

```
if any(word in message for word in bad_words) and user not in mods:
            sendMessage(s, "@" + user + " , You have been timed out for using bad language!")
            sendMessage(s, "/timeout " + user)
            break
```

Comment: `csv.reader` makes each line a list, so you're making a list of lists. If you only have a single line, why not just `return f.read().strip().split(',')`?

Comment: This works perfect thank you!! Me being a beginner at python found the list() in the documentation and hoped it worked..

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a list of a list. Just grab the first element of that list (the 0 position) to obtain the list format you're looking for